# Javafx: Menu background css

Tags: css, javafx

I am creating new application in Javafx and I have created Menu bar from javafx fxml and for that css is used to style it. But problem is that parent menu background changes to blue when I hover to sub menu item.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  It will help you ask better questions and get better answers.

Answer (score 4):

To do that, not only the `context-menu` class needs a custom rule, but also the `menu-item` and `menu` classes, e.g.:

```css
.menu, .menu-item, .context-menu {
    -fx-background-color: crimson;
}
```